# Apply texture/ structure to a plane with an image

Tags: texturing

I'm pretty new to blender and this might a simple question but I couldn't find exactly what I needed online, at least not with my keywords. How do I add an extra texture/ structure to a plane that got an image on it?

I got a wine bottle with a paper label, but of course this label isn't perfectly smooth and on top it should be made of some natural paper with some structure (fibers etc.).

But how can I apply this texture/ structure without overriding my original "texture" (label image).

I tried a texture into the `displacement` input of the `Material Output`, but this didn't really work as I expected it.

Texture:

[image: Texture]

Nodes:
[image: Nodes]

Result (with current setup):

[image: Result]

Quick example (made in Photoshop) what I want it to look like. Bottom original, top how I want it:
[image: Demo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to put an image as the texture of a plane is using the `import images as planes` add on. Go to `edit`, `preferences`, `add-ons` and search `images as planes`. Click the checkbox next to the add on and close the preferences window. Now, press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add to scene. Then, in the `mesh` menu there should be an option `image as plane`. Select that option, and choose your image. Please upvote and mark as accepted answer if this helps.

EDIT 
Based on what you are asking, instead of putting the texture into the displacement slot, you should add a `mix` node, connect that to the `surface` slot, put the current `Principled BSDF` node into the top slot and add a second `Principled BSDF` node with the image texture there. Fiddle with the `alpha` slider until it looks how you want. 
I'm on my phone right now, so I cannot guarantee that this answer will work. I will edit this response if this doesn't help, and I'll get onto my computer to test the answer first. However, if this helps, then you're welcome :).

Comment: Thanks. But thats what I already got. My label is imported like this. But on top of this I would like to give this label/plane/ image some structure by adding another texture to it

Comment: I'm not understanding what you mean my 'structure' and 'texture'. I can probably help if you clarify your intent a little bit.

Comment: I got the plane with my label as image on it. It looks like perfect white without any issues or "texture" on it. So I want it to another image on top of it with 50% opacity for example so the white gets some fibers on it

Comment: I added another picture to preview my needs.

Comment: I just edited my answer to help

Answer (score 1):

This is missing some screenshots, and preferably the images you are using as textures, but thankfully the problem is rather simple. Material nodes allow you to use SEVERAL textures in various ways for the material.

If the fiber texture is plain black and white, change its color space from sRGB to Non-Color Data, pipe it into the Height input of a Displacement node from the Vector category, then pipe the vector from that into the Displacement thing on the Shader Output node. Note that you will have to turn the Displacement strength down quite a bit in all likelihood.

If the fiber texture isn’t black and white, you might still get away with it, but… well, is it a normal map or just an image of fibers? It all depends.

For more information, see [The Blender Manual -> Rendering -> Shader Nodes](http://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. I will add some screenshots now. But I think the displacement nod already does the trick. I directly put the texture node into the `Displacement` of the `Material Output` node.

Comment: I added the screenshots and the texture. It's kind of working. But how can I make that texture finer and scale it down? I tried a `Texture Coordinate` into a `Mapping` into the `Image Texture` Node to make use out of the "seamlessness" (?). But it was kind of weird.

Comment: One more thing (sorry for the spam). I actually don't really need a displacement. All I need is just the fiber texture overlaying my label and mix it together somehow

Comment: @jona ok, that is much better. In this case, I might use the MixRGB node set to Multiply.